# Redirect 2 different domains to 2 different directory + .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, document-root

Here is my directory structure:

```
root
root/cakephp
root/wordpress
```

How to redirect

- `example.com/cakephp` to `cakephp` directory
- and redirect the rest of urls to `wordpress`

We have bespoke website that we want to configure it separately with cakephp and all the rerequest  like `example.com/cakephp` should go to cakephp directory and the rest of requestes goes to our CMS (which is wordpress in wordpress folder).

Comment: @anubhava There is nothing yet. I have to write it myself

Comment: After your edit looks like there is only one domain. What is your problem in using `cakephp` and `wordpress` in separate directories?

Comment: That's right. It's only one domain. We have bespoke website that we want to configure it separately with cakephp and our CMS to be configured in wordpress folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root .htaccess have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(cackephp|wordpress)/ wordpress%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. Working like charm

Comment: Sorry @anubhava. How if I want to 'example.com/order' goes to cakephp directory

Comment: Then add `RewriteRule ^order/?$ cackephp/ [L,NC]` before above `RewriteRule`